# Tom had already eaten when his friend arrived

Tags: vocabulary

Tom had already eaten when his friend arrived.
Tom had eaten when his friend arrived.

Do I need to add "already" in sentences above?

Comment: We can tell you that the sentence is intelligible and grammatical both with and without *already*, but whether it is *necessary* depends on what you want to say and we have no way of knowing that.

Comment: 'Tom had eaten when his friend arrived' might be being used for 'Tom had eaten when his friend had arrived'.

Comment: If you are concerned about either *had* or *already* , consider:    "Tom ate before his friend arrived."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to say "by the time his friend arrived, Tom was no longer hungry" then you would say "Tom had **already eaten** when his friend arrived".

If you want to say "at the time his friend arrived, Tom started his meal [likely dining together with that friend]", then you could phrase it as "Tom had eaten when his friend arrived", though it's a bit clumsy.

In short, "already eaten" implies a strict sequence (Tom ate, then his friend showed up) and "eaten when" implies simultaneity (vaguely). I'd only really expect to see the latter in a "stage setting" context, e.g. "Tom had eaten when his friend Col. Mustard arrived, so he was no longer hungry when the doorbell rang again, announcing the arrival of Mrs. Peacock".

Comment: I’d go a bit further than “a bit clumsy” myself and call it highly awkward to use “had eaten when X arrived” to mark simultaneity. “Tom had eaten when his friend was out, so he was no longer hungry” works fine, but if it’s the arrival being used, it implies that Tom started and finished his meal at the exact moment when his friend arrived, which would be a level of gulping down your food that no human oesophagus could withstand, I fear. A less punctual action than ‘arrive’ would be called for.